# Edit feature has misaligned process/tips suggestions sidebar

Tags: bug, design, editor

Please see screenshot below. You can see that the "How to edit" box is misaligned. I have tried this in Firefox Safe Mode(The default "Ubufox" on Ubuntu 12.04), and have tried it with all addons disabled. This is on Ask Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: Replicated in Chrome Linux. I'll try on Windows when I get to work, but I have a feeling it will be there as well. Seems like the `margin-bottom` might be a little low or something.

Comment: As far as I know, Ask Ubuntu is the only side which has a design created by someone external (Canonical). This would be better of at the Ask Ubuntu Meta.

Comment: @WaffelizedBobby design created by someone external, but Jin still did the majority of the work afaik.