# Rollback option only available when suggesting edits (not when you have full edit privs)

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits, edits, rollbacks

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12006367/revisions), I improved a suggested edit. Then someone came in and edited my edit and changed things like `I` to `i`. I then got that suggestion in the review suggested edit queue, so I tried to reject with a custom message explaining how the edit was wrong. That suggestion was [quickly approved by others](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/227799), then another edit was made to that. It happened much too quickly for me to intervene.

I figured I would go then and perform a roll-back, but when I try to edit the post, that option is not available.

[image: No Rollback?]

Looking at a [Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143894/179372) (I do not have full edit rights on Meta), I do see the rollback option on a normal edit (selecting the `edit` link at the bottom of the post). The question had already been previously edited — others that had not been edited logically did not have the drop-down.

[image: Has Rollback]

**Should the rollback always be available (*like when suggesting an edit*) or should it be harder to get to (*like when you are able to edit freely*)?**

Comment: Since when could you do rollbacks from the edit screen? I only know them from the post history...

Comment: Rollbacks can only be performed from within the revision history AFAIK: http://i.imgur.com/4gmEt.png

Comment: I do see that, and I'll go ahead and use it. However, I distinctly remember there being a drop-down when editing that allowed for a previous revision to be populated (i.e. rollback) where my red arrow points.

Comment: That you will get if you choose to explicitly edit an older revision (by using the edit link in the revision history) or (if I'm not mistaken) sometimes when an edit happened while you were editing at the same time. I might be wrong about the latter one though.

Comment: @Bart You're right again as far as how to get the drop-down. I may really be mistaken, but I recall seeing that on every (at least most) edit I used to make.

Comment: Quick thought, does this have anything to do with the fact that I recently earned full edit privileges? Perhaps the roll-back option is always available when merely *suggesting* an edit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a selector that allows you to choose a revision in the edit form, but that is not shown when you click on the edit link on the question page; it is shown when you click on the edit link on the revision page (in your case https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12006367/revisions).

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Probably, you remember you saw that selector, and thought it vanished.

If you are visiting the revision page, and you just wanted to rollback to a previous revision, the faster way is to click on the rollback link, rather than clicking on edit, and select a revision from the selector shown on the top.

[image: screenshot]

It makes sense to me to show that selector only when editing a revision from the revision page. I guess they removed the selector when editing a post from the question page because that selector was used in very few cases, in this case.

I would also remove the selector from where it is shown now, as I think that there are few users who start editing a revision (thus, making it the current revision of the post), change idea about that being the correct revision to use, select a different revision from that selector, and edit that revision (making it the latest revision for the post).
Users who start editing a revision, and decide that is not the right revision to edit (and make it the latest revision), can always select a different revision to edit even without the revision selector: They return to the page listing all the revisions, and click on the edit link for a different revision.

Where you don't have the privilege of editing every post, the edit form is the only way for you to suggest a rollback. If you didn't see the selector in the edit page, you could not suggest a rollback, as the rollback link is not visible to you in the revision page, in those sites where you cannot edit every post.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond with this nice, complete answer, however I think the scope of my question may have changed slightly. Performing a roll-back this way is obviously a good way to go, but there is a difference in general editing functionality between a "normal" edit screen and a "suggesting" edit screen. I have updated the question with those details.

Comment: I answered about that too.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The inline editor which you gain access to upon getting full edit privileges doesn't have a dropdown with the list of revision histories. This is [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98132/new-way-to-edit-bug-where-are-the-previous-edits) under the premise that using that dropdown isn't a very common use case, as waffles explains:

> We do not intend to have 100% parity with the full edit UI. I do not think that paralyzing users with too many extra options is a valid solution to your edge case.
>
> Now, if most of the time people needed access to this drop down, or even 10% of the time, something may be justified. But that is not the case.

Note that you can open the full editor in a new tab by right-clicking on the edit link if you need access to the full editor interface. You can also visit the revision history of the post and select the revision you want to edit using the "edit" link, which works in a similar fashion:

[image: edit link on revision history]

Comment: Thanks for the info, but why change the functionality between the two user-groups? As someone who just crossed over, it is a bit confusing to (not) see the tools that up until now were always available.

Comment: Adding those tools would introduce an additional level of complexity to the inline editor. As sourced from the post I linked to, the purpose of the dropdown in the full editor is primarily to give an indication that you're editing an older revision of the post. This isn't necessary for the inline editor, since you're using it to edit the most recent version of the post in place. Essentially, it's optimizing for the common use case, with the expectation that if you really do need to edit a previous version of the post, you can do so through the revision history.

Comment: I am accepting @kiamlaluno's answer, but this is just as valid a response for me. Thanks!