# Editor sidebar is misaligned when editing an existing post

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click to edit an **existing** question or answer here, in MSE. This question itself will do.
2. The sidebar appears below the editor block:

[image: misaligned sidebar]

Tested on Chrome 35 and Firefox 29 running on Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

This would seem to be a dupe of [Edit feature has misaligned process/tips suggestions sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143894/edit-feature-has-misaligned-process-tips-suggestions-sidebar), but it is happening here on MSE.

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox Aurora 32.0a2 on Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an old (like, *really* old – February 2009) inline style in place that should've been replaced with a CSS class long ago. Fixed in the next build.

Comment: Never too late!